# Latest Eclipse JBoss Tools and OpenShift 2 Login not working

Tags: eclipse, openshift, jboss-tools

I was working with OpenShift and Eclipse for a long time. Recently the Login dialog box is changed and it no longer logging in with username and password

I am getting the error as shown below

> Your credentials are not authorized to access 
>   "https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/user"

[image]

Did anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open eclipse internal web browser and give this URL `https://openshift.redhat.com/app/login`

The OpenShift login screen will appear and many number of SSL certificate prompt will appear. Press `Yes` to all SSL prompt and login to the console.

[image]

Once you are able to see your applications, then use the OpenShift Explorer Connection UI, then it should work.